# Slicing hex string by address range

Tags: python, python-2.7, hex, bit-manipulation

Let's say I have a hex string:

```
EPC = '00000800031C1060EC9FBD3C00000000'
```

The specification document specifies the address range for different fields the string represents. For e.g. address range 48h-53h (12bits), represents 'agency' field. I know (from experience) this represents 3 nibbles "1C1" in the hexstring EPC.

Likewise, I want to be able to decode other fields with their specified address range so my question is:

How do I use the address range information in the specification to extract the nibbles it represents from hexstring, EPC? More specifically, I am looking for a function of the following type:

```
def fun(addressrangeinhex,bits, hexstring):
    # addressrangeinhex is 48h-53h in my example above
    # hexstring is EPC string in my example above
    # bits is 12 bits in my example above
    return rangeofindexinhexstring
```

So using the function for my example I should get the (index=10, index=12).

Comment: Why do you need `bits` when you have the range? Isn't that redundant?

Comment: Yes it is. That's  just to keep the api consistent with the specification

Comment: What `EPC` is? Some kind of a variable/constant?

Comment: yes. A string variable

Comment: How should bit ranges that don't correspond to nibbles be handled? Also, 48 - 53 is **4 bits**, not 12. It represents one nibble, not 3. If the offsets are meant to be a nibble-count, there must be an offset, as there are only 32 hex digits.

Comment: Can you clarify the arguments some more, with real Python data types? Is the first argument the string `"48h-53h"`, or some other data type (like the int `0x48`)? Is the second argument a number of bits, or a number of bytes? What data type do you expect for the return value?

Comment: I don't see any way that `'48h-53h'` can refer to the substring `'1C1'` in your example string. That substring is either `'28h-33h'`, or maybe `'4Ch-57h'` if you're supposed to count from the right instead of the left.

Comment: @blckknght - i couldnt understand the hex addressing as well. maybe the specification is incorrect?but that thats a long shot..

Comment: Can't see a way to associate 48h-53h with 1C1 from the example provided. Could you may be post more details or examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution takes the approach of specifying the bits to extract using the string from the specification. ie: `'48h-53h'`.  The hex value to extract those register bits from is also expected to be a string.  In addition this function can get values that are not on nibble boundaries.

**Code:**

```
def get_sub_register_value(sub_reg_bits_addr, bit_string):
    """
    Given a register address description string, and a register value
    string, return the bits from the value described by the address

    :param sub_reg_bits_addr: string of the form '48h-53h'
    :param bit_string: register value string of the form,
        '00000800031C1060EC9FBD3C00000000'
    :return: returns string of sub register: eg
    """
    start, end = (int(x[:-1], 16) for x in sub_reg_bits_addr.split('-'))
    value = int(bit_string, 16)
    mask = (1 << (end - start + 1)) - 1
    return ("%x" % ((value >> start) & mask)).upper()
```

**Test Data:**

```
EPC = '00000800031C1060EC9FBD3C0000000'
agency = '48h-53h'
pattern = 'FEDCBA98765432109876543210'

assert get_sub_register_value(agency, EPC) == '1C1'
assert get_sub_register_value('0h-3h', pattern) == '0'
assert get_sub_register_value('1h-4h', pattern) == '8'
assert get_sub_register_value('5h-8h', pattern) == '0'
assert get_sub_register_value('5h-9h', pattern) == '10'
assert get_sub_register_value('4h-9h', pattern) == '21'
assert get_sub_register_value('3h-9h', pattern) == '42'
```

Answer (score 2):

Have it in bit string and index there:

```
bits = '{0:0128b}'.format(int(EPC,16))
agency = int(bits[40:52],2)

print(hex(agency))  # 1C1
```

Comment: where do 40 and 52 come from? looks like these are the numbers the requestor is asking for and once we have them we could do the trick even without bit transormations - EPC[40/4:52/4]